# lambda function doesn't work with each

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use lambdas as blocks for an array each:

```
(1..10).each ->(i) {p i}
```

But I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Why does it happen? The lambda has exactly one argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Range#each` doesn't take a lambda, it takes a block. The lambda is being passed as an argument, which `Range#each` is not expecting. Try this instead:

```
(1..10).each { |i| p i }
```

You can convert a lambda if you are so inclined:

```
lam = ->(i) { p i }
(1..10).each(&lam)
```

Comment: Thanks, What does that ampersand do?

Comment: It tells Ruby to treat the argument as the method's block.

Comment: In this case you could also use `map`, `(1..10).map.each { |i| p i }`

Comment: @chemical `map` doesn't really add anything here.

Comment: `(1..10).each &->(i) {p i}` and `(1..10).each(&method(:p))`.